# How to specify border side on flutter RaisedButton

Tags: flutter

I'm animating a RaisedButton to turn it to "Outline", but i need to have no border on left side. Has any way to make something like this?

My RaisedButton code:

```dart
RaisedButton(
  color: _previousColorTween.value,
  elevation: 0,
  onPressed: _previousStep,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
    topRight : Radius.circular(30),
    bottomRight : Radius.circular(30),
    side: BorderSide(
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    ),
  ),
  child: Icon(
    Icons.keyboard_arrow_left,
    size: 30,
    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
  ),
);
```